# Populating a listview with arrayList of custom objects

Tags: java, android, listview, custom-adapter

I've been trying my hand at android for a few weeks now but hit a snag with populating a listview with custom objects. I've tried several tutorials on stack overflow and youtube but when the app is run it crashes at list.setAdapter(adapter). But I have no clue as to what causes is.

Here is my most recent attempt:

```
public class NPCEditor extends Fragment{

    View myView;
    ArrayList<NPC> NPCs = new ArrayList<>();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.npc_edit, container, false);

        populateNPCList();
        populateListview();

        return myView;
    }

    private void populateNPCList(){
        NPCs.add(new NPC(40, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, "", "", "", "", "", "", ""));
        NPCs.add(new NPC(50, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, "", "", "", "", "", "", ""));
        NPCs.add(new NPC(60, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, "", "", "", "", "", "", ""));
        NPCs.add(new NPC(70, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, "", "", "", "", "", "", ""));
        NPCs.add(new NPC(80, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, "", "", "", "", "", "", ""));
    }

    private void populateListview(){
        ArrayAdapter<NPC> adapter = new NPCAdapter2();
        ListView list = myView.findViewById(R.id.NPCList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class NPCAdapter2 extends ArrayAdapter<NPC>{
        public NPCAdapter2(){
            super(getActivity(), R.layout.npc_layout, NPCs);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            View itemView = convertView;
            if(itemView == null){
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.npc_layout, parent, false);
            }
            NPC currentNPC = NPCs.get(position);
            TextView txtAge = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textAge);
            txtAge.setText(currentNPC.getAge());
            return  itemView;
       }
    }
}
```

And the xml files
npc_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Age" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And NPCEditor layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/NPCList"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="327dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Logcat:

beginning of crash

> 04-22 10:43:56.986 12587-12587/blackanvil.com.dmi E/AndroidRuntime: > FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                       Process: blackanvil.com.dmi, PID: 12587
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
>   getLayoutInflater()Landroid/view/LayoutInflater; in class
>   Lblackanvil/com/dmi/NPCEditor; or its super classes (declaration of
>   'blackanvil.com.dmi.NPCEditor' appears in
>   /data/app/blackanvil.com.dmi-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk)
>                                                                           at blackanvil.com.dmi.NPCEditor$NPCAdapter2.getView(NPCEditor.java:53)
>                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2497)
>                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1930)
>                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:722)
>                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:783)
>                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1721)
>                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2254)
>                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16966)
>                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5604)
>                                                                           at
>   android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
>                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16966)
>                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5604)
>                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:398)
>                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
>                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16966)
>                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5604)
>                                                                           at
>   android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
>                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16966)
>                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5604)
>                                                                           at
>   android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:132)
>                                                                           at
>   android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
>                                                                           at
>   android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
>                                                                           at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:869)
>                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16966)
>                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5604)
>                                                                           at
>   android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1172)
>                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16966)
>                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5604)
>                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:398)
>                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
>                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16966)
>                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5604)
>                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2022)
>                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1865)
>                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1774)
>                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16966)
>                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5604)
>                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:398)
>                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
>                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16966)
>                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5604)
>                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2022)
>                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1865)
>                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1774)
>                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16966)
>                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5604)
>                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:398)
>                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
>                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2817)
>                                                                           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16966)
>                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5604)
>                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2635)
>                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2329)
>                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1367)
>                                                                           at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6974)
>                                                                           at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:922)
>                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:724)
>                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
>                                                                         at android.view.Ch 04-22 10:43:57.117 12587-12587/blackanvil.com.dmi
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12587 SIG: 9

Comment: There seems to be a lot of problems with your code. Crash log please.

Comment: @tahsinRupam I've added the Logcat to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
itemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.npc_layout, parent, false);
```

Comment: It's an improvement. The app no longer crashes but the listview remains empty :/

Comment: Add your NPC class!

Answer (score 0):

I've found this tutorial which worked like a charm form me. Hopefully others find it just as useful.

https://www.sitepoint.com/custom-data-layouts-with-your-own-android-arrayadapter/